# Webservice, unable to set cast in program

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webservice

Unable to set cast from url in program. MainActivity to MoviesActivity and further my program goes as shown below.
Can you tell me how to set images also. I am still learning.

**Screenshot**[image]

```
public class Movies extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
        new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesData.txt");
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<MovieModel>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<MovieModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");
                List<MovieModel> movieModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    MovieModel movieModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), MovieModel.class);
                    movieModelList.add(movieModel);
                }
                return movieModelList;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
                try {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
            listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        }
    }
```

---

```
  public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

        private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MovieAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<MovieModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            movieModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource,null);
                holder.ivMovieIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
                holder.tvMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovie);
                holder.tvTagline = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagline);
                holder.tvYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
                holder.tvDuration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
                holder.tvDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);
                holder.rbMovieRating = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbMovie);
                holder.tvCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCast);
                holder.tvStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStory);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.tvMovie.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getMovie());
            holder.tvTagline.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getTagline());
            holder.tvYear.setText("Year : " + movieModelList.get(position).getYear());
            holder.tvDuration.setText("Duration : "+ movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());
            holder.tvDirector.setText("Director : " +movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());
            holder.rbMovieRating.setRating(movieModelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for(MovieModel.Cast cast : movieModelList.get(position).getCastList()){
                stringBuffer.append(cast.getName() + ", ");
            }

            holder.tvCast.setText("Cast : " + stringBuffer);
            holder.tvStory.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getStory());
            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            private ImageView ivMovieIcon;
            private TextView tvMovie;
            private TextView tvTagline;
            private TextView tvYear;
            private TextView tvDuration;
            private TextView tvDirector;
            private RatingBar rbMovieRating;
            private TextView tvCast;
            private TextView tvStory;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MovieModel {

    private String movie;
    private int year;
    private float rating;
    private String duration;
    private String director;
    private String tagline;
    @SerializedName("cast")
    private List<Cast> castList;
    private String image;
    private String story;

    public String getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(String movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getTagline() {
        return tagline;
    }

    public void setTagline(String tagline) {
        this.tagline = tagline;
    }

    public List<Cast> getCastList() {
        return castList;
    }

    public void setCastList(List<Cast> castList) {
        this.castList = castList;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public void setStory(String story) {
        this.story = story;
    }

    public static class Cast {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/avengers" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMovie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:text="MovieName"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTagline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvMovie"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvMovie"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvMovie"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:text="Tag Line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTagline"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTagline"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTagline"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Year" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Duration" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDirector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:text="Director" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rbMovie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:stepSize="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cast"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rbMovie"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbMovie"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Story"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCast"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCast"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCast" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this change your layout file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/redfox" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMovie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MovieName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTagline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tag Line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Year" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Duration" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDirector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Director" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cast"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Story" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rbMovie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:max="5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

Comment: Yes, its working. But what is problem in my layout? Thank you for the answer.